# One question about array without default constructor in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, copy-constructor

From previous post, I learnt that for there are two ways, at least, to declare an array without default constructors.  Like this

```
class Foo{
  public:
  Foo(int i) {}     
};
   Foo f[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   Foo f[5] = {Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3), Foo(4), Foo(5)};
```

I also learnt that the first one will construct the object using the parameter directly and the second copy constructor is used here. However, when I test the code below. I make the copy constructor private. I expect to see the difference of the copy constructor usage. But it is not what I expected. Neither of the two declarations is working.

```
class Foo{
  public:
  Foo(int i) {}     
  private:
  Foo(const Foo& f) {}
};
int main(){

   Foo f[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   Foo f[5] = {Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3), Foo(4), Foo(5)};      
}
```

Can anybody explain to me why does this happen?

Comment: @skydoor: Now you have asked exactly 100 questions :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first won't construct the objects directly. It will first construct a temporary `Foo`, and then copy the `Foo` into the element. It's similar to your second way. The difference is that your second way won't work with a `explicit` copy constructor, while your first will. And conversely, the first will not work with a `explicit` constructor taking `int`, while the second will. Stated another way, the first constructor used in the initialization of an element must not be `explicit`.

Notice that neither way needs to copy. But they still need to check whether the copy constructors are accessible. So, they shall behave *as-if* they would copy, but they don't really need to do the copy.